# Flask, Gunicorn, Nginx :: IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to move a project from development to production. (At dev stage, I was using only `Flask`, and now I'm running it behind `Gunicorn` with `Nginx`.)

I'm having a problem to serve a specific page, `songs.html`.

The page loads correctly with a dummy variable (`jukebox = [whatever]`), but in real life I'm using a generator, like so:

```
playlist= query_playlist(p)
jukebox = next(playlist)

return render_template('songs.html',
                        jukebox=jukebox)
```

and this function takes a while (say 2s) to return results...but results are not being served, and process just hangs after results are returned.

I run the app like so:

```
(appenv)$gunicorn -c gconfig.py app:app
```

**wsgi.ppy**

```
from app import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**gconfig.py:**

```
workers = 16
worker_class = 'sync'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 120 # changed this from 30 up
keepalive = 2
```

**nginx.conf** (`brew` installation)

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host                 $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
        }
```

If I run the app using `python app.py`, back to dev stage:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(use_reloader=True, threaded=True, debug=True)
```

at least I get the following traceback:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/Apps/app/appenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/Apps/app/appenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 261, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/Users/me/Documents/Code/Apps/app/appenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 236, in write
    self.send_header('Server', self.version_string())
  File "/Users/me/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 412, in send_header
    self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

so does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT**

I get the same traceback even with results taking 2s to be processed.

Comment: The socket was closed from the client site because it took too long. That results in a `Broken pipe`. In general keep response times low. Everything longer than 1s is bad for user experience, everything above 3s requires special considerations like what gunicorn worker type to use and how to prevent this to be a DoS attack vector.

Comment: You can try streaming the results instead of generating a response in memory *then* serving it

Comment: and how do I go about doing that? could you point me the way?

Comment: @KlausD. I see. actually, this is a process that on a final stage will run on the background.

Comment: @KlausD. Actually, even with 1 sec I get the same traceback...it is breaking anyway.

Comment: Are you raising a StopIteration in your generator?

Comment: @NikolaJankovic explicitly, no. would you care to see the generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Flask [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/streaming/) (and following #arielnmz sugestion), you can stream your content:

```
from flask import Response, stream_with_context

@app.route('/playlist')
def generate_playlist():
    def generate():
        jukebox = query_playlist(p)
        for i in jukebox:
            yield i[0]['artist'] 
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()))
```

Each yield expression is directly sent to the browser.

The trick is to have an inner function that uses a generator to generate data and to then invoke that function and pass it to a response object.

This works.